# Is there any way to alter the behaviour of Android restarting Activities after a crash

Tags: android, crash

After reading through all the questions on SO regarding this topic i am extremely annoyed by this.

Crashes will happen, no one writes perfect code. And there are apps that require a certain logical hierarchy. The best example is the login-screen idea, where you are in some activity doing something on a server and now the app crashes. After a restart, the app lost all its login-session data and saving it might not be the safest idea. So presenting the user with the login screen after a crash would be the best and most logical thing to do. The best user experience.

However Android decides to remember the Activity stack but only restart the last working activity with a "blank" application under it.
The only viable option i see would be to check in EVERY single activity if some login state is available or not and if not, start the login (launcher) activity with a clear-top or clear-task. But this almost forces you to write a base `extends Activity` class in which this behavior is implemented and then all activities have to extend that. But what if, for some reason, you cannot extend it because you need to extend some other type of activity?

There is `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` but this happens every single time the user returns from exiting via home button. There is the antagonist `finishOnTaskLaunch` that finished an activity every time the user presses the home button. So the Android devs are aware that sometimes one would like the app to appear in a certain state after exit but a crash seems to be exclusive to all that.

Using a custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` gives me some chance to act after a crash but as the apps state is unrecoverable i can only perform certain tasks that will happen in addition to Android very own behavior.

So my simple question is, if there is any way, that is built into Android, that allows me to change the after-crash-behaviour of Android in a natural way that does not depend on the version it's running (to some extent ofc) and will result in a somewhat smooth user experience.

Comment: I have this same issue, app restarts itself but has no access to all the data set in Room, so it logs my user out. On crash the app should close, but instead it's in a strange zombie state.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the proper way of obtaining the result you would like would be to provide a proper parent or up navigation stack. You can read about it more here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html.

But the gist of it would be to use the idea of parent activities to provide proper back navigation. If the activity already exists it will just go back to it, if it doesn't (such as in the crash scenario) it will launch the correct activity when the user navigates back.

[NavUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) is a handy class to help build this behavior and is part of the support library which would work on a range of different API levels.

Comment: this does not change the fact that the user lands in a blank application where certain things never happened because the activities were never executed (in this new process), no sessions/logins etc.